# Snowflake User's Default Role Does Not Exist

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm looking to create a database with access for a single user using the following script:

```
USE ROLE ACCOUNTADMIN;
CREATE DATABASE db;
USE DATABASE db;
CREATE WAREHOUSE wh
    WAREHOUSE_SIZE = SMALL
    ;
CREATE ROLE new_role;
GRANT USAGE ON DATABASE db TO ROLE new_role;
GRANT CREATE SCHEMA ON DATABASE db TO ROLE new_role;
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA db.PUBLIC TO ROLE new_role;
CREATE or replace USER new_user PASSWORD='' DEFAULT_ROLE = 'new_role' DEFAULT_WAREHOUSE='wh';
GRANT ROLE new_role TO USER new_user;
GRANT ALL ON WAREHOUSE wh TO new_role;
```

When attempting to login with the newly created user, or connect from
another service, I see the following error:

> User's configured default role 'new_role' does not exist or not
>   authorized. Contact your local system administrator, or attempt to
>   login using a CLI client with a connect string selecting another

Setting the default role to `PUBLIC` allows me to log in from the Snowflake web portal. I can then select the desired role and navigate as expected. The third party connection cannot access any of the newly created objects, presumably because it does not attempt to switch roles.

What is missing to allow the default role to be set for my new user?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should remove the quotes around the role name: `DEFAULT_ROLE = new_role`

`ROLE` names *are case sensitive*, and the syntax is just like column names:
`COL_NAME`, `col_name` and `"COL_NAME"`  are the same, but  `"col_name"` is different, ie. lower case.

I would recommend you *not* to quote such identifiers, and let the system implicitly transform references in whatever casing to uppercase.  This is what most people do.

All these ways of setting the `DEFAULT_ROLE` are valid and equal:

```
ALTER USER u SET DEFAULT_ROLE = NEW_ROLE;
ALTER USER u SET DEFAULT_ROLE = new_role;
ALTER USER u SET DEFAULT_ROLE = "NEW_ROLE";
ALTER USER u SET DEFAULT_ROLE = 'NEW_ROLE';
```

The following however are different from above, as `ROLE` names are case sensitive:

```
ALTER USER u SET DEFAULT_ROLE = 'new_role';
ALTER USER u SET DEFAULT_ROLE = "new_role";
```

The `DEFAULT_ROLE` is just a text property and can be set to *anything*, eg. non-existing roles or roles that are not granted to the user.  Both will generate errors at login.

Use the following command to see the exact name of the `DEFAULT_ROLE` setting in effect:

```
DESC USER u;
```

NB: The `DEFAULT_ROLE` setting is not a role grant !
You need to use `GRANT ROLE r TO USER u` also.

Comment: This is odd, because Snowflake alters the strings from user input to all caps. So you can successfully create a name with lower, and it will need to be referenced as UPPER.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Unquoted references are transformed into uppercase, but that is nothing new, that's the way most SQL entities work for most databases.  colum_name and "COLUMN_NAME" are the same.  However, if you really want to leave Kansas, you can mess with the QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS_IGNORE_CASE parameter...

Comment: Details in https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the commands you posted were copy/pasted, perhaps the issue is because your

`DEFAULT_ROLE='new_role'`

should not have the role name in quotes:

`DEFAULT_ROLE = NEW_ROLE`

?

The example from the docs link is as follows:
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/admin-user-management.html#using-sql

```
create user janesmith password = 'abc123' default_role = myrole must_change_password = true;
```

The ALTER command in that document does have the role name in quotes, but that may be an error, or perhaps the name should actually be in CAPS also.

I hope this helps...Rich